# Bluemix top menu bar disappears

Tags: ibm-cloud

Sometimes the menu bar (with menu items for DASHBOARD, SOLUTIONS, CATALOG, PRICING, etc.) at the top of the Bluemix masthead disappears when I re-size my browser window. How can I access these menu items when running with limited screen space and a narrow browser window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions move to the "hamburger" menu selector in the upper left corner based on the responsive design

Comment: Additionally from our design team "We are hoping to make a better responsive solution soon".

Answer (score 1):

This is on purpose.  The Bluemix console has a responsive design so features degrade as the browser window gets smaller.  This is on par with what bootstrap does.

If you have any feature suggestions please leave it as a comment below and I can get it to our design team.

Answer (score 0):

See this animated gif for how to access the collapsed menu items on mobile devices - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeccF.gif